# Creating thumbnails of multiple images?

Tags: image, codeigniter

I am uploading max 5 images and i want to create the thumbnails of those 5 images i am successful in uploading and saving image name in database but can't able to make thumbnails.

//controller

```
        $files = $_FILES;
        $cpt = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
        for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
                {
                $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']= $files['uploadfile']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['uploadfile']['type']= $files['uploadfile']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']= $files['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['uploadfile']['error']= $files['uploadfile']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['uploadfile']['size']= $files['uploadfile']['size'][$i];
                $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
                $this->upload->do_upload('uploadfile');
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $name_array[] = $upload_data['file_name']; //success till here now inserting in database and creating thumbnails
                $fileName = $upload_data['file_name'];
                $images[] = $fileName;
                }
              $fileName = $images;
              var_dump($images);
              @$form['picture1']=$images[0];
              @$form['picture2']=$images[1];
              @$form['picture3']=$images[2];
              @$form['picture4']=$images[3];
              @$form['picture5']=$images[4];
```

//

```
private function set_upload_options()
  { 
  // upload an image options
         $config = array();
         $config['upload_path'] = LARGEPATH; //give the path to upload the image in folder
         $config['remove_spaces']=TRUE;
         $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; // for encrypting the name
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
         $config['max_size'] = '78000';
         $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
         return $config;
  }
```

now i want as 5 images are uploaded in folder at the same time thumbnails  of those 5 images are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my solution :

```
private function _makeThumb($source, $filename, $num = 5)
{
    $config2['image_library']  = 'gd2';
    $config2['source_image']   = $source;
    $config2['new_image']      = THUMBPATH.$filename;
    $config2['create_thumb']   = TRUE;
    $config2['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config2['width']          = 75;
    $config2['height']         = 50;
    return $config2;


}
```

then i can call this function in a loop to create a thumnails

Answer (score 1):

You can use CodeIgniter's Image Manipulation Class for thumbnails creation: check [CodeIgniter 3 manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html?highlight=thumbnail#processing-methods)

Comment: yeah already tried that but no go... actually making thumbs for single image works but not for multiple images

Comment: @JAVA_RMI Simply use loop over the array with images